# Salesforce Mobile SDK - Hybrid App

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

For hybrid app development I am getting error in installing force hybrid saying sfdx version as lower but I have the most recent one.

C:\Users\Darshan>forcehybrid version
Missing tools

Installed sfdx is less than the minimum required version (6.0.0).
Please upgrade your version of sfdx.

Answer (score -1):

step 1: Uninstall the salesforce sfdx
step 2: Delete the SF folder from C drive -> Program Files
step 3: Install the sfdx cli with below command
**npm install -g sfdx-cli@7.209.6**

This worked for us

Comment: Why that specific version? It's 8 months out of date at this point and that part of the CLI has been abandoned in favor of `sf` version 2. `npm install @salesforce/cli@latest -g` seems like it would be more appropriate here.

Comment: An answer to the question I posed seems to be answered [in this mobileSDK community feed](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007YvwYnSAJ). For when Salesforce inevitably nukes that link, current versions of the SDK just check for a version number instead of seeing if people are using `sf` instead of `sfdx`. This should be fixed in Mobile SDK v12.0+

Comment: Thanks everyone for the support 